# OpenCV Face detection with score very slow

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am using following OpenCV Python interface function to detect a face:

```
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
```

It detects all faces correctly and runs within a few milliseconds.

Because I need to know the scores I then used:

```
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale3( gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(30, 30), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, outputRejectLevels = True)
```

The problem is that it's runtime is 3 minutes and it does only provide on detected face, which is wrong.

What are possible errors? Did anyone use the detectMultiScale3 function successfully?

Comment: Did you try to specify all the other parameters? `image[, scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[, minSize[, maxSize[, outputRejectLevels]]]]]]) → objects, rejectLevels, levelWeights`

Comment: Yes, like that:
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale3(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,
    outputRejectLevels = True
)

Comment: Is there a better way to get the detections including score. The score has to be calculated anyway. Probably it would even be faster to write a small program in C++ and call it in python?

Comment: maybe it could be worth having a look at the source code, what's really going on there... I guess the python code are c/c++ wrappers anyway

Comment: Yes, that true: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/modules/objdetect/include/opencv2/objdetect.hpp
But how does it help?

Comment: The default parameters are the same, the only difference are the two new result vectors.